# Difference between Azure Log Analytics and OMS Portal

Tags: monitoring, azure, oms

I have a Linux VM with omsagent running, that is shown as "Connected" in OMS Portal. But in Azure Log Analytics it is shown as "Not Connected" and if i click on connect "Error".

So what is the difference between Azure and OMS Portal. what is missing on my VM?

Comment: Log Analytics is a service in Operations Management Suite (OMS) that helps you collect and analyze data generated by resources in your cloud and on-premises environments.

Comment: Do you have  more detailed error logs?

Comment: Maybe you could check as the link. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-vm-extension#troubleshooting-linux-virtual-machines

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Looking through the URL you posted, there are two things to add. 1. I didn't install omsagent via the waagent extension, because this does not work on my unsupported distribution. 2. My instance is happily streaming syslog and heartbeat messages to Log Analytics. It is just that Azure does not mark it as connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference seems to be if the azure vm extension is installed.

Check if it is installed with:

```
azure vm extension get <resource-group> <vm-name>
```

See also
https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-extensions-features